# How to detect 32-bit or 64-bit OS in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash

I need to detect 32-bit or 64-bit OS through Flex.

```
var osName : String = Capabilities.os;
```

This only gives Windows XP or Windows 7. I need to detect 64-bit Windows XP. Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Does [`Capabilities.supports64BitProcesses`](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/system/Capabilities.html#supports64BitProcesses) do the trick for you?

Comment: This is only for Flex 4 correct? I get a compiler error for Flex 3. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: I haven't checked, but since it's not a Flex class I'd guess it's player-version-dependent and not Flex-version-dependent.  Try targeting player version >= 10.0.32 (if that's an acceptable limitation on clients).